# Manually adding google analytic code to different urls through jQuery AJAX

Tags: ajax, url, google-analytics

I'm working on a progressive page loading script where new pages will load continuously when bottom of the page is reached. I'm using ajax to fetch the data dynamically through jQuery ajax from the server, the return data will return the url of the new post as well as its content.

My problem is what code should I use to submit my returned post url to analytic so that it registers as a valid page view?

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://somedomain.com/fetch_pages.php',
data: { 'page': this.$loadMoreCounter , 'section': that.$section },
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) { 

    //analytic code upon each successful callback.

});
```

Comment: Have you looked at this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#tracking_virtual_pageviews

Comment: thanks will have a look